# Facebook Device Flow Support

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

According to the [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/), [OAuth Device Flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-05#section-3.7) is supported.

However, when I follow their directions on starting the Device Flow process, I receive a status code of 400 (Method not implemented).

Has anyone successfully able to get the Facebook Device Flow process functioning?

---

curl -X post [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id={appId}](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id=%7BappId%7D)

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
      Invalid method in request<P>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

About your specific error, it seems facebook docs made you do it wrong: FAIL

You must send a POST request, which you're asking cURL to do, but request data must not be part of the URL. Instead, you should use the -d option to specify the sent data and use the URL up to the ? sign, like shown in [this *superuser* question](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool)

But! Even if you used the right HTTP method, you'd get an error that reads:

> Unsupported type: 'device_code'. Supported types: web_server, user_agent, client_cred, username

Now the best part: this happens unless you use the client_id facebook themselves used for [their demo](https://oauth-device-demo.appspot.com/)! In that case, you get a 200 (OK) response with the expected code, user_code and verification_uri. Apparently their application is somehow different from those we're trying with. No hint in the app configuration page about this.

By the way, I haven't found anyone claiming to have successfully used facebook's Device Flow, have you?

Comment: Facebook bug:  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/166716050078293  Comments suggest that this feature is not openly available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example implementation, but I haven't managed to get it working with my own project:
https://oauth-device-demo.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error.

look this  article

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=105132

it's  teach your how set app, but after trying, nothing change~

you can try~